# How to get Flutter Draggable to work with Agora Video frame

Tags: flutter

I have this video calling Application I am working on. Everything seems to be falling in place. I have a small issue with one UI effect I am trying to implement.

So here is the situation:
When on a live call, like on messenger or any other video calling application, I want user 0, to be able to drag and place their video frame at different positions in the screen.

I tried this using flutter draggable:

```
/// Video 0 View Customization to include draggable effect
  Offset? position;
  double prevScale = 1;
  double scale = 1;

  void updatePosition(Offset newPosition) =>
      setState(() => position = newPosition);
  ValueNotifier<Offset?> positionNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);
```

`/// Video layout wrapper`

```
  Widget _viewRows() {
    final views = _getRenderViews();
    switch (views.length) {
      case 1:
        return Container(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[_videoView(views[0])],
        ));
      case 2:
        return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                _expandedVideoRow([views[1]]),
                Positioned(
                  left: position == null
                      ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5
                      : position!.dx,
                  top: position == null ? 50 : position!.dy,
                  child: Draggable(
                    maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                    feedback: Transform.scale(
                      scale: scale,
                      child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              child: _expandedVideoRow([views[0]]))),
                    ),
                    childWhenDragging: Opacity(
                      opacity: .3,
                      child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: scale,
                        child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                child: _expandedVideoRow([views[0]]))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onDragEnd: (details) => updatePosition(details.offset),
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: scale,
                      child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.2,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              child: _expandedVideoRow([views[0]]))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ));
   
      default:
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

These is then displayed in another main stack:  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Stack(
fit: StackFit.expand,
children: [

```
       if (widget.calltype == 'videocall') ...[
           child: _viewRows(),
      ]
     ...
```

[image]

Is there any better way to attain this UI Draggable effect?

Comment: Hey were you able to figure out this issue ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this @LearnToday?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this widget to make it draggable
https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_widget